# Is it okay to write "grid-template-columns: 1fr;" if I only have one column on small window sizes?

Tags: css, media-queries

For display sizes under `500px` width, I would like to have only one column for my grid. Is it okay to write `grid-template-columns: 1fr;` for this? Or would be another option better? Maybe just `grid-template-columns: 1;`?

Thanks.

Example:

```css
#grid {
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

Comment: clarify *better*. I see at least 4 or 5 different ways to define one column

Comment: Edited the question :)

Comment: you didn't clarify *better*. You simply added your code. Your question as stated is opinion based.

Comment: My question is only: Is it okay if I do it like that? Or is it a mistake somehow?

Comment: If it works then it's ok. If it doesn't work then it's a mistake.

Comment: It seems that it works ... but I am not sure if it's compatible to all browsers in all situations

Comment: If you're looking for browser support then you must look up the property/technology you're using.